# Using $location without html5 mode enabled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using Rewrite on the server side to configure all my routing. My site has quite a complicated system, e.g. different roles for users, which is currently all taken care on the server side. I am trying to use $location, however when I enable html5 mode then no href redirects work. I read that I need to redirect all calls to index.html on server side. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you added <base href="/" /> to your <head />??.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this point:
**How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode** in 
/https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

You could get help from this.